# How to find the invariant factors of a matrix given its Jordan canonical form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Suppose we have a matrix $A \in M_{12}(\mathbb{C})$ whose Jordan canonical form is

$$J_1(0) \oplus J_1(0) \oplus J_2(0) \oplus J_2(0) \oplus J_1(\sqrt{2}) \oplus J_1(\sqrt{2}) \oplus J_1(-\sqrt{2}) J_1(-\sqrt{2}) \oplus J_1(i\sqrt{2}) \oplus J_1(-i\sqrt{2})$$

Then how would we go about finding the invariant factors given this? And how do we tell how many invariant factors there are going to be?

I know that the first is going to the minimal polynomial which must be

$$m_A(t) = t^2(t^2-2)(t^2+2)$$

and they have to product together to give the characteristic polynomial, which is

$$p_A(t)= t^6(t^2-2)^2(t^2+2)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $J_n(a) = aI+J_n(0)$ with $(J_n(0) v)_j=v_{j+1},v \in \Bbb{C}^n$ should tell you everything you need

Comment: You should ask yourself where the $m_A(t)$ came from. Surely it's from the rightmost summands for $0$, $\sqrt{2}$, $-\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{-2}$,and $-\sqrt{-2}$? So ignore these blocks, and  now the next factor will come from rightmost summands left; and then thirdly, .. and fourthly we get a $t$ from the last $J_1(0)$.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now, so $a_1(t) = t^2(t^2-2)(t^2+2)$, $a_2(t) = t^2(t^2-2)$, $a_3(t) = a_4(t) =t$ right?